# @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment: Unsafe assignment of an any value

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

Consider the following code:

```js
const defaultState = () => {
  return {
    profile: {
      id: '',
      displayName: '',
      givenName: '',
    },
    photo: '',
  }
}

const state = reactive(defaultState())

export const setGraphProfile = async () => {
  const response = await getGraphProfile()
  state.profile = { ...defaultState().profile, ...response.data }
}
```

Which generates the ESLint warning:

> @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment: Unsafe assignment of an any value.

This means that the properties in `response.data` might not match the ones of the `profile`. The return of `getGraphProfile` is `Promise<AxiosResponse<any>>`. Of course it's easy to get rid of this ESLint warning by simply ignoring it:

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
state.profile = { ...defaultState().profile, ...response.data }
```

#### Questions:

- How is it possible to shape the data in the Promise `getGraphProfile` so it does match?
  Because one can create a TS `interface` but that would simply create duplicate code with the object `defaultState().profile`
- Why is TypeScript not having an issue with this code but the linter does? Do both not need to be alligned?

#### The implementations:

```js
const callGraph = (
  url: string,
  token: string,
  axiosConfig?: AxiosRequestConfig
) => {
  const params: AxiosRequestConfig = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: url,
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
  }
  return axios({ ...params, ...axiosConfig })
}

const getGraphDetails = async (
  uri: string,
  scopes: string[],
  axiosConfig?: AxiosRequestConfig
) => {
  try {
    const response = await getToken(scopes)
    if (response && response.accessToken) {
      return callGraph(uri, response.accessToken, axiosConfig)
    } else {
      throw new Error('We could not get a token because of page redirect')
    }
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(`We could not get a token: ${error}`)
  }
}

export const getGraphProfile = async () => {
  try {
    return await getGraphDetails(
      config.resources.msGraphProfile.uri,
      config.resources.msGraphProfile.scopes
    )
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(`Failed retrieving the graph profile: ${error}`)
  }
}

export const getGraphPhoto = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await getGraphDetails(
      config.resources.msGraphPhoto.uri,
      config.resources.msGraphPhoto.scopes,
      { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }
    )
    if (!(response && response.data)) {
      return ''
    }
    const imageBase64 = new Buffer(response.data, 'binary').toString('base64')
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access
    return `data:${response.headers['content-type']};base64, ${imageBase64}`
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(`Failed retrieving the graph photo: ${error}`)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't generate warnings, only errors. As far as TS is concerned, that `any` assignment is valid. This is where the linter comes in to offer additional support.

Luckily you don't need to duplicate your interface. Use TypeScript's `ReturnType` to get the type of the `profile` object in your `defaultState` method:

```js
type IProfile = ReturnType<typeof defaultState>["profile"]
```

The above line utilizes 3 great TypeScript features:

- `ReturnType` to infer the type that a function returns
- `typeof` to infer the interface from an object instance
- `["profile"]` to get the type of a certain property of an interface

Now, make your `callGraph` function generic:

```js
function callGraph<T>(url: string, token: string, axiosConfig?: AxiosRequestConfig) {
  const params: AxiosRequestConfig = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: url,
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
  }
  return axios.request<T>({ ...params, ...axiosConfig })
}
```

And update the `callGraph` call in your `getGraphDetails` function:

```js
...
  if (response && response.accessToken) {
    return callGraph<IProfile>(uri, response.accessToken, axiosConfig)
  }
...
```

Now your graph calls are properly typed, and you didn't have to duplicate your profile definition; rather you used TypeScript's awesome type inference technique to "read your interface" from the return type of your function.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. I've updated the OP because `getGraphPhoto` also depends on `getGraphDetails`. Your answer is perfect! Thank you

Comment: Ah, sure, you can also generalize your `getGraphDetails` function. I'll upload a gist in a moment.

Comment: I'd argue that this is typing things in the wrong direction. The data doesn't flow from the defaultState function to the API call -- it flows the other way. What happens if the defaultState function changes? That would cause the typing of the API response to change, but that might not be desireable. I would explicitly create a type based on the API response data and then import that type to use as the return value for defaultState

Comment: In this case the `defaultState` represents both. So it would be desired to have them updated both at the same time when needed.

Comment: @DarkLite1 Check this out: https://gist.github.com/ArashMotamedi/46bc668c8f4fff4986fc7ac1e0523e8e General point is that you can make several functions generic, and pass the generic parameter (i.e. `T` in above examples) from one generic function to the next. `getGraphDetails<T>` can call `callGraph<T>`.

Comment: That's true, but ultimately the API call is where the data originates. Therefore, the type of defaultState is dependent on the type of the API response. By using the ReturnType approach, the API data is dependent on the defaultState function. I realize it works now because their types match up. And maybe in this particular case it's unlikely that they will ever not match up. But as a general rule of thumb, you should type things in the direction the data is flowing through your app. In more complex cases, this will prove to be the only manageable way to do things.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much. Now I have the solution and need to apply because `defaultState` is in another file than the Promises. I'll figure that one out. Thx again for the amazingly detailed answer.

Comment: Eric's point is valid, and you generally want to instantiate your objects (and return types from functions) based on a declared interface. But I also wanted to show you the amazing power of TS to work backwards, inferring an interface from an instance of an object or function. TypeScript offers no real type safety anyway, just development-time type hints, and the TS inference is just so delightful! But yes, for a more complex solution, please declare your interfaces first, and make sure your server and client share/agree on them.

Answer (score 10):

Going to answer your questions in reverse order:

> Why is TypeScript not having an issue with this code but the linter does? Do both not need to be alligned?

In Typescript, something with type `any` can be assigned to *anything*. Using `any` essentially removes typesafety from that part of the code. For example:

```
const foo: number = 'hello' as any // Typescript is fine with this
```

I guess the point of that eslint rule is to catch places where you might not be wanting to actually assign something with type `any` to something else. To be honest, I'm not quite sure why one would use that linting rule given that the compiler option `noImplicitAny` exists.

> How is it possible to shape the data in the Promise getGraphProfile so it does match? Because one can create a TS interface but that would simply create duplicate code with the object defaultState().profile

There are a few ways you could solve this. The simplest approach would probably be to type the return value of `getGraphDetails`:

```
type GraphDetailsPayload = {
  id: string,
  displayName: string,
  givenName: string,
}

export const getGraphProfile = async (): Promise<GraphDetailsPayload> => {
  ...
}
```

But usually it's better to type the data at as low a level as possible, which in this case means the `callGraph` function:

```
const callGraph = (
  url: string,
  token: string,
  axiosConfig?: AxiosRequestConfig
): Promise<GraphDetailsPayload> => {
  const params: AxiosRequestConfig = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: url,
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
  }
  return axios({ ...params, ...axiosConfig })
}
```

By doing it that way, now `callGraph`'s return value is typed, and TS will therefore know that `getGraphDetails` and `getGraphProfile` both return that same type, since they ultimately just pass through the API response.

Last option: I don't use Axios, but I bet its Typescript definition would let you do this:

```
const callGraph = (
  url: string,
  token: string,
  axiosConfig?: AxiosRequestConfig
) => {
  const params: AxiosRequestConfig = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: url,
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
  }
  return axios<GraphDetailsPayload>({ ...params, ...axiosConfig })
}
```

I have removed the `Promise<GraphDetailsPayload>` return type, and have instead just "passed in" the `GraphDetailsPayload` type via the angle brackets to the `axios` function call. This is making use of something called "generics", which are the most fun and complex part of typesystems like TS. You'll encounter them a lot in libraries you use, and you'll eventually start writing functions that take generics as well.

Comment: Setting `noImplicitAny` in `tsconfig.json` does not throw an error for that line, so it's not 100% the same logic. How would you solve this?

Comment: @DarkLite1 updated my answer, I submitted it too soon. I would expect that `noImplicitAny` would throw an error in other places though, places that eventually flow through to the line in question.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I also have `getGraphPhoto` depending on `getGraphDetails`, added code to the OP. In this case there's an issue setting the type on `getGraphDetails` and even on `getGraphPhoto`. I'll figure it out :)

Comment: I'll give your solution another thought, because your remarks are valid. The data does flow from the API call upwards. I just think I need to implement the type on `getGraphProfile` because `getGraphPhoto` only retuns a string. I've updated the OP to include all code.